# zsh ls: look for multiple extensions, no error if some don't exist

Tags: zsh, wildcard, ls

In a zsh terminal I want to `ls` all video files, that is all files ending with .mp4 or .mkv or .avi or .mov (for example).

When I do `ls *.mp4 *.mkv *.avi *.mov` it does what I want, *except* if there are no files with one or more of the given extensions.

E.g. if there are no .avi files, the above command won't list any of the other files but only say:

> ls: *.avi: No such file or directory

I noticed in bash instead of zsh, it also gives this error but then still shows the files that do exist.

I assume this has to do with a difference in how wildcard matching / globbing works in zsh and bash environments.

Is there a way to just `ls` all files with a bunch of given extensions (or other wildcard patterns) regardless if they all occur or not?

Comment: `ls *.(mp4|mkv|avi|mov)` or if `KSH_GLOB` is set, `ls *.@(mp4|mkv|avi|mov)` (this one also works with ksh93 and if `extglob` is set, bash)

Comment: @RocketNuts : You have now got several answers for your question. Please consider accepting one ot them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need more than one line of code to get this right.

You *could* simply get rid of the error message by using the *null glob* flag, i.e.

```bash
ls *.mp4(N) *.mkv(N)
```

However, the problem with this is that if a pattern then produces no matching files, this results in it expanding to exactly 0 paths.

This is fine if, say, there are no `mp4` files, but at least one `mkv` file. Your command line would then be simply interpreted as

```bash
ls file.mkv
```

However, if there are neither `mp4` nor `mkv` files, the command line would be interpreted as

```bash
ls
```

which will show you a list of **all** files in your working directory.

Perhaps this is good enough for interactive work. If you do this from within a script, a better approach would be to first load all matching files into an array and then test whether the array is empty:

```bash
files=( *.mp4(N) *.mkv(N) )
if (( $#files )); then
  ls $files
else
  print 'No mp4 or mkv files`
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Zsh has a couple of [shell options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Expansion-and-Globbing) you can change to modify this behavior:

```
% unsetopt nomatch  # If a pattern has no matches, pass it thru unmodified.
% ls *.mp4 *.mkv *.avi *.mov
ls: *.avi: No such file or directory
ls: *.mkv: No such file or directory
ls: *.mov: No such file or directory
ls: *.mp4: No such file or directory
% setopt nullglob   # If a pattern has no matches, simply remove it.
% ls *.mp4 *.mkv *.avi *.mov
%
```